# Subfunctions and private functions

Tags: octave

I'm working on a package for octave and something odd is happening.  In the foo function for class A I make a recursive call using cellfun like this:

```
... cellfun(@(d) foo(d,localval), cellarray ) ...
```

Now function foo is defined for several different classes. I've previously used this practive successfully.  The difference this time is that, in class B, foo makes use of two subfunctions and functions private to class B.  This causes the above call to result in the following error:

```
error: 'subfunction2' undefined near line 29 column 6
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/packages/mypkg/@B/foo.m at line -1, column -1
```

I've tried changing the order in which subfunctions are listed in the function file for @B/foo and have verified that it finds the first subfunction but not the second. I also tried making the subfunctions private to class B and the problem persisted.

So my question is this: What's happening here?  Is it the use of cellfun? The anonymous function? Why does it catch one subfunction to foo but not two? Objects classes? What's up with the line/column -1 being reported? I'd really like to hide these helper functions from the user, so I'd prefer something other than dropping the subfunctions in the public path.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was not at all what my question made it out to be.  It turns out I had an open if statement (i.e. no endif) in one of the subfunctions.  I discovered it when I moved the two subfunctions to their own function files and placed those files in a public directory in the package. Calling the function from here caused a parse error to trigger.

So, Octave programmer be warned. Syntax errors in subfunctions lead to unexpected error messages. In this case the system seemed to just ignore the erroneous function and proceed without its definition. This, in turn, lead to an undefined function error.